# Keil microVision "Cannot download file ... Cannot write destination file"

Tags: arm, keil, cmsis

[image]

Trying to download the ARM::CMSIS-RTOS pack my mouse is hovering over and I get the errors in red at the bottom ("Cannot download file http://www.keil.com/pack/ARM.CMSIS-RTOS_Validation.1.1.0.pack: Cannot write destination file"). The project is saved in a file I have complete access to - the only answer I've found for why this may occur.

Any help would be massively appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is Keil unable to help you?  It seems more appropriate to ask them for tech support on their products.  http://www.keil.com/support/contact.asp

Comment: No luck on that front, Fred

Answer (score 0):

Searching the Keil support forum the problem appears that you do not have write privileges to the folder that the pack installer is downloading to.  Run as admin or manually install.